# Is it possible to use the return type of a function within that function's argument types?

Tags: typescript

For example, when I try to do this:

```
function chain<A, B extends (input: A, loop: (input: A) => C) => any, C extends ReturnType<B>> (input: A, handler: B): C {
   const loop = (input: A): C => handler(input, loop);
   return loop(input);
}

chain('test', async (value, loop): Promise<string> => {
   const ready = await someExternalThing();
   if (ready) {
      return value;
   } else {
      return await loop(value + '!');
   }
});
```

Even with a strict return type defined for the handler function, the loop function's return type in the bottom code is still showing up as "any"

Does anybody know any way around this issue?

Comment: Your type `B` is a function returning `any`, why not define a generic type `D` or reuse `C`?

Comment: @GaëlJ I've already tried the generic type approach, it didn't work. Also, re-using C would be a circular type reference, since C is just defined as the return type of B anyways.

Comment: Tricky problem you got there. Very circular dependency prone.

Comment: TBH I don't understand the purpose of the `chain` function. But as you wrote it, `C extends any`, There is no type safety provided by `C`.

Comment: @GaëlJ The chain function is a general purpose recursion thingy. I've used it several times for filesystem traversal, waiting on promises then checking a value (like the example), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works and do what you want as far as I understand:

```js
function chain<A, C> (input: A, handler: (input: A, loop: (input: A) => C) => C): C {
   const loop = (input: A): C => handler(input, loop);
   return loop(input);
}

chain<string, Promise<string>>('test', async (value, loop) => {
   const ready = await someExternalThing();
   if (ready) {
      return value;
   } else {
      return await loop(value + '!');
   }
})
```

The key being to specify the generic parameters when calling `chain`.

Comment: Yes, I got the same when I was trying to find a solution. Is there a way to derive the return value from the given return type of the handler function?
(His handler function was `async (value, loop): Promise<string>` where you omitted the type)

Comment: I didn't manage to do it but this doesnt mean it's not posssible. Though this solution seems fairly acceptable to me.

Comment: I tried some more and give up. I don't think there is a straight forward way in current typescript. Every time I introduce the circular dependency between the output and the input value of the lambda function, the type falls back to `unknown`.

Comment: If you look at my response (edited), I got SO close. But I don't typescript is there yet.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to derive the template parameters automatically from the return type of the handler. Still searching for a solution there.

But if you are willed to give the template parameters manually, there is a solution for you:

```js
let i = 0;

async function someExternalThing() {
    i += 1;
    return i > 3;
}

async function chain<VAL, RET>(
    input: VAL,
    handler: (input: VAL, loop: (input: VAL) => Promise<RET>) => Promise<RET>
): Promise<RET> {
    const loop = (input: VAL): Promise<RET> => handler(input, loop);
    return loop(input);
}

const result = chain<string, string>('test', async (value, loop) => {
    const ready = await someExternalThing();
    if (ready) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return await loop(value + '!');
    }
});

result.then((value) => {
    console.log(`Result: ${value}`)
})
```

```
Result: test!!!
```

And not a single type in the script is `any` or `unknown`.

---

### Further research

This one seems to work:

```
async function chain<VAL, RET>(
    input: VAL,
    handler: (input: VAL, loop: (input: VAL) => Promise<RET>) => Promise<RET>
): Promise<RET> {
    const loop = (input: VAL): Promise<RET> => handler(input, loop);
    return loop(input);
}

const result = chain('test', async (value): Promise<string> => {
    return value;
});
```

But as soon as you introduce the `loop` parameter, `RET` goes back to `unknown`. So I feel like it's a limitation of the typescript type inferring mechanism at the moment. I think it might work in future.

```
async function chain<VAL, RET>(
    input: VAL,
    handler: (input: VAL, loop: (input: VAL) => Promise<RET>) => Promise<RET>
): Promise<RET> {
    const loop = (input: VAL): Promise<RET> => handler(input, loop);
    return loop(input);
}

const result = chain('test', async (value, loop): Promise<string> => {
    return value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solutions of Gael J and Finomnis, I decided to make a version that only requires specifying one type parameter, rather than two:

```
class Chainer<A> {
   run <B>(input: B, handler: (input: B, loop: (input: B) => A) => A) {
      const loop = (input: B) => handler(input, loop);
      return loop(input);
   };
}

new Chainer<Promise<string>>().run('test', async (value, loop) => {
   const ready = await someExternalThing();
   if (ready) {
      return value;
   } else {
      return await loop(value + '!');
   }
});
```

It uses a class as a sort of holder for the handler return type, then uses the `run` method to inference the "input" type from the first argument.

**Another Method**

Using a wrapper function instead of a class:

```
function chain<A> () {
   return <B>(input: B, handler: (input: B, loop: (input: B) => A) => A) => {
      const loop = (input: B) => handler(input, loop);
      return loop(input);
   };
}

chain<Promise<string>>()('test', async (value, loop) => {
   const ready = await someExternalThing();
   if (ready) {
      return value;
   } else {
      return await loop(value + '!');
   }
});
```